# Basic Cloud Firestore security rules setup

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am currently using this default code to secure my Cloud Firestore database:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
  }
}
```

This code works fine and the simulation is fine.

I tried to update the code and use the new default code I find in every guide:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
  }
}
```

But this code fails every time, the access is not granted.

In the simulation, I just try to read a document in a Collection named "parameters".

Am I missing something here? My plan is to harden the security access afterwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok my bad, I actually realised that the database access rules and the storage access rules have their own and separate security panels.

I was trying to update the storage rules with the default database rules...